# Pair of Random Numbers without Common Factors

Tags: pgfmath, random-numbers

My goal is to define `\avar` and `\bvar` such that they are integers between 1 and 11 inclusively but share no common factors and they should never be equal.

I think that the code I've written should do that, but sometimes it does not and I don't know why.

Is there a fundamentally easier way to do this? Or is there an easy way to fix the code I've got?

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{multicol}


\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}


\newcommand{\InitVariablesDOS}
{%
 % This randomly sets \avar to be a whole number between 1 and 10.
 % I am using the list format so that when I'm not doing a MWE,
 % I can easily weight, say, 7s to come more often.
 % Let's say in our example \avar is randomly set to 6....
 \pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{avar}{{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}{10}}
 \pgfmathrandomitem{\avar}{avar}

 % If \avar=6 I want \bvar to share no common factors (other than 1) with 6.
 % So, \bvar is selected from {DOSIfSix},
 % which are whole numbers which do not have the factors 2,3, or 6.
 \pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{DOSIfOne}{{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}{10}}
 \pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{DOSIfTwo}{{1}{3}{5}{7}{9}}
 \pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{DOSIfThree}{{1}{2}{4}{5}{7}{8}{10}}
 \pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{DOSIfFour}{{1}{3}{5}{7}{9}}
 \pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{DOSIfFive}{{1}{2}{3}{4}{6}{7}{8}{9}}
 \pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{DOSIfSix}{{1}{5}{7}{11}}
 \pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{DOSIfSeven}{{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{8}{9}{10}}
 \pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{DOSIfEight}{{1}{3}{5}{7}{9}}
 \pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{DOSIfNine}{{1}{2}{4}{5}{7}{8}{10}}
 \pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{DOSIfTen}{{1}{3}{7}{9}{11}}

 \ifcase\avar\relax% This should define \bvar so that it shares no common factors with \avar. 
  \or \pgfmathrandomitem{\bvar}{DOSIfOne}
  \or \pgfmathrandomitem{\bvar}{DOSIfTwo}
  \or \pgfmathrandomitem{\bvar}{DOSIfThree}
  \or \pgfmathrandomitem{\bvar}{DOSIfFour}
  \or \pgfmathrandomitem{\bvar}{DOSIfFive}
  \or \pgfmathrandomitem{\bvar}{DOSIfSix}  
  \or \pgfmathrandomitem{\bvar}{DOSIfSeven}
  \or \pgfmathrandomitem{\bvar}{DOSIfEight}
  \or \pgfmathrandomitem{\bvar}{DOSIfNine}
  \or \pgfmathrandomitem{\bvar}{DOSIfTen}
 \fi
 \xdef\bvar{\bvar}
}


\newcommand{\avarandbvar}
{%
\InitVariablesDOS
\(avar=\avar\)

\(bvar=\bvar\)

\vspace{0.5cm}
}

\newcommand{\manyavarandbvars}[1]{\foreach \x in {1,...,#1} {\avarandbvar}}


\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{5}
\manyavarandbvars{70}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is sitting inside a loop, did you try making `\avar` global too ?

Comment: I don't really know what your comment means. I need `\avar` and `\bvar` to be generated a whole bunch of times so I can make series of math exercises.

Comment: you are declaring `\bvar` to be global via `\xdef`. Do the same thing to `\avar`

Comment: Wow, I think that fixed it! But why did that work? ... and what does 'global' really mean? [I copy/pasted `\xdef` into my code weeks ago due to advice, but I never really knew what it meant/did.]

Comment: Euclid's algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) is the usual test for common roots.

Comment: Global does mean that the value of a control sequence is available outside of its group (i.e. the current newcommand).

Answer (score 3):

For comparison, here is a luatex based solution. (I use ConTeXt, but it should be straightforward to translate this to LaTeX as well). To make it more challenging, I generate the list of `bvars` algorithmically.

I wasn't sure why some lists went until 10, while others went until 11. In the code below, all lists go until 10.

```
\startluacode
  -- Euclid's algorithm for gcd
  local gcd = function(m, n)
    while m ~= 0 do
      m, n = math.mod(n,m), m
    end
    return n
  end

  local avars = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
  local bvars = {}

  -- Generate bvars
  for i = 1, #avars do
    local a = avars[i]
    if bvars[a] == nil then
      local b = {1}
      for j = 2, 10 do
         if gcd(a, j) == 1 then
            b[#b + 1] = j
          end
      end
      bvars[a] = b
    end
  end

  local random, format = math.random, string.format

  local sampleAandB = function()
    local i = random(#avars)
    local a = avars[i]
    local j = random(#bvars[a])
    local b = bvars[a][j]

    return a, b
  end

  local avarandombvar = function()
    local a, b = sampleAandB()
    context.dontleavehmode()
    context.framed({"frame=off, align=middle"}, format("avar = %s \\crlf bvar = %s", a, b))
    context.blank{"big"}
  end

  interfaces.definecommand ("avarandombvar", {macro = avarandombvar})

\stopluacode

\starttext

\startcolumns[n=5]
\dorecurse{70}{\avarandombvar}
\stopcolumns

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First the solution for your pronlem:

You need to preserve `\avar` to keep it from changing. This can be done adding `\edef\avar{\avar}` after `\pgfmathrandomitem{\avar}{avar}`.

As a recommendation: you can move the declarations of the random lists into the preamble. This way, they are defined only once and not every time `\InitVariablesDOS` is used. And you should comment out the line ends of several lines in `\InitVariablesDOS`. Otherwise they can produce spurios spaces, depending on where the macro is called.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{multicol}


\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{avar}{{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}{10}}
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{DOSIfOne}{{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}{10}}
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{DOSIfTwo}{{1}{3}{5}{7}{9}}
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{DOSIfThree}{{1}{2}{4}{5}{7}{8}{10}}
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{DOSIfFour}{{1}{3}{5}{7}{9}}
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{DOSIfFive}{{1}{2}{3}{4}{6}{7}{8}{9}}
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{DOSIfSix}{{1}{5}{7}{11}}
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{DOSIfSeven}{{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{8}{9}{10}}
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{DOSIfEight}{{1}{3}{5}{7}{9}}
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{DOSIfNine}{{1}{2}{4}{5}{7}{8}{10}}
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{DOSIfTen}{{1}{3}{7}{9}{11}}

\newcommand{\InitVariablesDOS}
{%
 \pgfmathrandomitem{\avar}{avar}%
 % added as workaround
 \edef\avar{\avar}%
 % to show the problem, uncomment the next line and comment out the previous one
% \(avar=\avar\)

 \ifcase\avar\relax% This should define \bvar so that it shares no common factors with \avar. 
  \or \pgfmathrandomitem{\bvar}{DOSIfOne}%
  \or \pgfmathrandomitem{\bvar}{DOSIfTwo}%
  \or \pgfmathrandomitem{\bvar}{DOSIfThree}%
  \or \pgfmathrandomitem{\bvar}{DOSIfFour}%
  \or \pgfmathrandomitem{\bvar}{DOSIfFive}%
  \or \pgfmathrandomitem{\bvar}{DOSIfSix}%
  \or \pgfmathrandomitem{\bvar}{DOSIfSeven}%
  \or \pgfmathrandomitem{\bvar}{DOSIfEight}%
  \or \pgfmathrandomitem{\bvar}{DOSIfNine}%
  \or \pgfmathrandomitem{\bvar}{DOSIfTen}%
 \fi
 \edef\bvar{\bvar}%
}


\newcommand{\avarandbvar}
{%
\InitVariablesDOS

\(avar=\avar\)

\(bvar=\bvar\)

\vspace{0.5cm}
}

\newcommand{\manyavarandbvars}[1]{\foreach \x in {1,...,#1} {\avarandbvar}}


\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{5}
\manyavarandbvars{70}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Now the reason for the problem:

In this case, it has nothing to do with groups and/or making `\avar` global. The problem comes from `pgf` and how it defines a macro with `\pgfmathrandomitem`. If the latter is called for different macros, e.g.

```
\pgfmathrandomitem{\avar}{avar}
\pgfmathrandomitem{\bvar}{bvar}
```

the second call will also change the result of the first. Therefore, the first result has to be preserved with `\edef\avar{\avar}`.

The details (you may stop reading here):

The macro is simply defined with `\def` (pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex, lines 241 and 242):

```
\pgfmathrandominteger{\pgfmath@randomtemp}{1}{\pgfmath@randomlistlength}%
\def#1{\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#2@\pgfmath@randomtemp\endcsname}}}
```

As can be seen, the contents of the macro depends on `\pgfmath@randomtemp`. If it changes, the macro changes too. And this will happen every time `\pgfmathrandomitem` is called, even if this is done for a different macro from a different list.

Since I can't think of a reason for using `\def` instead of `\edef` here, which would prevent this problem, I would consider this a bug.